# Rollup, typescript, react native component library config setup

Tags: typescript, react-native, rollup

I'm trying to use rollup with the config below to bundle an expo react native app for npm publish, but at the moment I have the following error when I try to build with rollupJs:

```
$ rollup -c

src/index.ts → lib/index.js...
[!] Error: Unexpected token
node_modules/react-native/index.js (14:7)
12: 
13: // Components
14: import typeof AccessibilityInfo from './Libraries/Components/AccessibilityInfo/AccessibilityInfo';
           ^
15: import typeof ActivityIndicator from './Libraries/Components/ActivityIndicator/ActivityIndicator';
16: import typeof Button from './Libraries/Components/Button';
Error: Unexpected token
```

my rollup.config.js that I mostly inherited, but I have checked online and most configs are like this:

```
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import image from '@rollup/plugin-image';
import copy from 'rollup-plugin-copy';

const packageJson = require('./package.json');

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
      {
        file: packageJson.module,
        format: 'esm',
        sourcemap: false,
      },
    ],
    plugins: [
      peerDepsExternal(),
      resolve(),
      commonjs(),
      typescript({
        tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
        exclude: ['./lib/**', './story/**', './App.tsx', '**/__tests__/**'],
      }),
      terser(),
      image(),
      copy({
        targets: [{ src: 'assets/avatar_default.png', dest: 'lib/assets' }],
      }),
    ],
    external: [...Object.keys(packageJson.peerDependencies || {})],
  },
  {
    input: 'lib/types/index.d.ts',
    output: [{ file: 'lib/index.d.ts', format: 'esm' }],
    plugins: [dts()],
  },
];
```

not sure where I'm going wrong, it certainly has worked before

Comment: Could it be because you are trying to import a type into a JS (not TS) file? I'm pretty sure I've had a lot of those mistakes too.

Comment: @carlosV2 negative, just looked through again, can't find a place I imported or put a type in a .js file, it's all mostly .tsx files I have